# MAUI ContentView can't access a component

Tags: c#, maui

With `Maui`, I'm trying to create an expansion panel with an arrow. The arrow has to be like *ChevronRight* (>) when the panel is closed and *ChevronDown* when it is open.

I have this XAML. In here, I named the `Image` as `imgIcon`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentView xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/dotnet/2021/maui"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:hlp="clr-namespace:LanguageInUse.Helpers"
             x:Name="expand"
             x:Class="LanguageInUse.Components.ExpansionPanel">

    <ContentView.ControlTemplate>
        <ControlTemplate>
            <VerticalStackLayout>
                <VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                    <TapGestureRecognizer Tapped="TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped" />
                </VerticalStackLayout.GestureRecognizers>
                <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" VerticalOptions="FillAndExpand">
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="30" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <Image x:Name="imgIcon" WidthRequest="10">
                        <Image.Source>
                            <FontImageSource 
                                Glyph="{Binding Source={x:Reference expand},Path=Arrow}"
                                Color="Black"
                                FontFamily="FAS" Size="10" />
                        </Image.Source>
                    </Image>

                    <ContentView Grid.Column="1" 
                         Content="{Binding Source={x:Reference expand},Path=HeaderContent}" />
                </Grid>
                <ContentPresenter 
                    IsVisible="{Binding Source={x:Reference expand},Path=IsExpanded}" />
            </VerticalStackLayout>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </ContentView.ControlTemplate>
</ContentView>
```

When I tap the `Grid` the content is display but the image doesn't change and always display the *ChevronRight*.

```
private string _arrow = FontAwesomeIcons.ChevronRight;
public string Arrow
{
    get => _arrow;
    set => _arrow = value;
}  

private void TapGestureRecognizer_Tapped(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    IsExpanded = !IsExpanded;

    Arrow = IsExpanded ? FontAwesomeIcons.ChevronDown : 
            FontAwesomeIcons.ChevronRight;
}
```

So, I tried to change the `FontImageSource` of the `Image`

```
imgIcon.Source = new FontImageSource() { 
    Glyph = IsExpanded ? FontAwesomeIcons.ChevronDown : 
    FontAwesomeIcons.ChevronRight };
```

but the `imgIcon` is not found in the code.

### Update

I created a *ViewModel*

```
public partial class ExpansionPanelViewModel : ObservableObject
{
    [ObservableProperty] private string _arrow;

    public ExpansionPanelViewModel()
    {
        Arrow = FontAwesomeIcons.ChevronRight;
    }
}
```

in the constructor of the `ContentView` I added

```
ExpansionPanelViewModel vm;

public ExpansionPanel()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    BindingContext = vm = new();
}
```

and I changed the line to

```
<Image x:Name="imgIcon" WidthRequest="10">
    <Image.Source>
        <FontImageSource 
            Glyph="{Binding Source={x:Reference expand}, Path=Arrow}"
            Color="Black"
            FontFamily="FAS" Size="10" />
    </Image.Source>
</Image>
```

but it doesn't find the icon.

Comment: you can't access elements of a template by name.  You need to use data binding, and the property you're binding to needs to be `Observable`

Comment: I added a ViewModel and referenced it in the `ContentView`. It doesn't seem to work. Is it correct how I did it? I added an update.

Comment: you should not need the `Source` attribute in the binding expression

Comment: I tried `{Binding Arrow}` and `{Binding vm.Arrow}` but the icon is not displayed

Comment: Could you please post the code of `ExpansionPanel.xaml.cs` ? And since a contentview is usually a reused control, we generally don't set the `BindingContext` directly in its constructor. We will generally set the value of its Bindable Property in the page where it is used.